# Google maps API address validation in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am writing functionality for checking an entered addresses validity with google API. The user types in street number, street name, suburb etc which then looks up google api
and returns a formatted address which is closest suited to the entered address.

I have got the following so far:

```
public string getFormattedAddress(string address)
{
     string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%" + address + "&key=" + MyStaticMethods.GOOGLE_API_KEY;
     object result = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
     string json = result.ToString();
     JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
     ...
}
```

But i'm having trouble reading the response from the API. The following is pseudocode of what I want to do:

```
var streetNumber = apiResult.streetNumber

var address = apiResult.address;

var postcode = apiResult.postcode;
```

I also want a way of telling if the API lookup could not find any matching addresses for the given address.

Any help would be great,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use this library:
https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net

Example:

```
 GoogleGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder();
 IEnumerable<GoogleAddress> addresses = await geocoder.GeocodeAsync("1600 pennsylvania ave washington dc");    
 var country = addresses.Where(a => !a.IsPartialMatch).Select(a => a[GoogleAddressType.Country]).First();    
 Console.WriteLine("Country: " + country.LongName + ", " + country.ShortName);     
//Country: United States, U
```